# .htaccess rewrite rules for two or more PHP files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

right now I have .htaccess file to rewrite url for my profile.php (root directory)

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

This codes transform `http://127.0.0.1/projects/webproject/profile.php?username=sarah` into `http://127.0.0.1/projects/webproject/sarah`

**Situation:**
Say, I have "update_availability.php" (root directory), and access it with this format `http://127.0.0.1/projects/webproject/update_availability.php?month=03&day=18&year=2014`.

I want to change the URL into `http://127.0.0.1/projects/webproject/update_availability.php/03/18/2014`.

**What I want to know:**

1. is it possible to have one .htaccess file (root directory) and rewrite rule for other php file?
2. How can I transform `http://127.0.0.1/projects/webproject/update_availability.php?month=03&day=18&year=2014` **into** `http://127.0.0.1/projects/webproject/update_availability.php/03/18/2014`.

I am new to .htaccess. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: 1) Its possible. 2) Like you did for profile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webproject/

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(update_availability(?:\.php)?)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1?month=$2&day=$3&year=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```